# Typedef for a pointer to a C function inside C++

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to declare a function pointer **type** (not a variable) that would specify C calling convention. Both

```
extern "C" typedef void (*PFunc)();
```

and

```
typedef extern "C" void (*PFunc)();
```

produce a syntax error, when used on function level.

```
extern "C" { typedef void (*PFunc)(); }
extern "C" typedef void (*PFunc)();
```

both work when used on the global scope; I'd rather keep it local.

What's the proper way, please? I don't want to use compiler specific extentions.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594178/why-do-you-need-extern-c-for-c-callbacks-to-c-functions), matching calling conventions between the pointer and the target is the safe thing to do when calling inderectly functions that are declared as `extern "C"`, because C and C++ calling conventions might mismatch. In real life they mostly don't, but still, correctness.

Comment: `extern "C" typedef void (*PFunc)();` compiles fine for me with gcc 4.8.1 and clang 3.4

Comment: In global scope or within a function?

Comment: I'm convinced that this is not supposed to compile. `extern` applies to entities with linkage. Types have no linkage. In the example you show it makes sense, because the code declares a function (which is an entity with linkage). Also, `extern` is not part of a type ever. You cannot restrict something to be extern.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: in global scope.

Comment: @pmr I agree, I also think the `extern "C"` isn't necessary at all. The function pointers look exactly the same in c and c++. There's no mangling involved for a type definition.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not about mangling, but calling convention. Which is not part of the function pointer but the function.

Comment: Calling convention is a part of a function pointer definition. Short of `extern "C"`, I know of no standard way of declaring a function pointer to a `cdecl` function. Just try assigning a `(*)(void)` to a `(* __fastcall)(void)`.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I responded the same elsewhere: calling convention is a property of a function, not of a function pointer. In the example you link it is important that the function used as a callback has C calling convention, but this is not really required by the type signature.

Comment: Elaborate on _calling conventions_ please? I think there's no difference, as long everything is build with the same compiler toolchain.

Comment: How are parameters passed, who clears the stack. On x86/Win32, cdecl implies caller cleanup, stdcall is a callee cleanup.

Comment: Language linkage is a part of a functions type; people should read 7.5 of the C++ standard. In particular, "Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical". You can only use `extern "C"` at namespace scope so you have to do the `typedef` there. [See also this GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2316). To further point it out: when a C API declares a function pointer `typedef`, **your function has to have C language linkage or your program is ill-formed according to the standard**.

Comment: `extern "C" typedef void (__fastcall *PFuncFast )();` compiles (global scope)... no *conflict* for a 'cdecl' from `extern "C"` and the explicit calling convention...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: One compiler can support multiple calling conventions. Indeed, it _must_...

Comment: Looks like global scope it is. @Simple - make an answer, please

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, I see. But then it **must** be handled at namespace level!

Comment: It would be possible with http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1463 , but I haven't found an EWG issue on the EWG issues list for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what some commenters have said here, calling convention/linkage *is* part of a function type. It has to be, otherwise this information would not be known when calling the function through the function pointer:

> `[C++11: 7.5/1]:` All function types, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage have a language linkage. *[..]*

The correct declaration is:

```
extern "C" typedef void (*PFunc)();
```

However, at block-scope, you cannot declare a function to have any linkage:

> `[C++11: 7.5/4]`: Linkage specifications nest. When linkage specifications nest, the innermost one determines the language linkage. A linkage specification does not establish a scope. **A *linkage-specification* shall occur only in namespace scope (3.3).** In a *linkage-specification*, the specified language linkage applies to the function types of all function declarators, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage declared within the *linkage-specification*. *[..]*

So, you will have to stick with a namespace-scope declaration. If you still want to restrict the visibility of the declaration, you could "shelter" it from other code in the same translation unit, using an *unnamed namespace*.

Comment: +1; please mention the scope for the benefit of future generations, otherwise the answer makes no sense.

Comment: I think the OP's concern was to declare such `typedef` within a function level scope. May be you should explicitly mention this isn't possible in this case.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: I'm sorry? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's specifically about declaring such a type at block scope? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I tried to declare it on the function level (because locality). It's a syntax error there. I've already found a workaround (`extern "C"{...}` on the global scope) by the time I wrote the question. By now, I see that my original goal is pretty much unattainable; @Simple got there first in a comment. Scope is not a big deal for me; it's a matter of style, not correctness.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev You can always use a unnamed namespace, to make the `typedef` module private.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Final answer now edited in. Hopefully a quote from the standard will satisfy you.

Comment: That's enlightening. However, I'm still confused why two functions with different linkage but identical arguments/return value will not fail `static_assert(is_same<decltype(f1), decltype(f2)>::value, "")`. So, they have distinct type, but I'm not able to check that in the language?

Comment: @pmr: They do not have distinct type. They have distinct _linkage-specifications_.

Comment: Is there any reason `extern "C"` must appear *before* the typedef or is it just because the syntax Gods willed it that way? If the linkage was *part* of the function type I would've expected to see it after the typedef.

Comment: @SergeantPenguin: Good question; dunno!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, linkage specification (`extern "C"`) should be in namespace scope (or global) by Standard.
`extern "C" typedef void (*pf)();`
is right. If your compiler doesn't accept it, it is a bug of the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Guessing, but it might be because you are declaring the function as (), in C that means it can take both an INT and VOID... Try explicitly saying `(void)`

Comment: The question has a simplified example; in real project, it has arguments.

Comment: [sarcasm]
Thanks for voting me down for giving an answer based on the information you gave! Forgive me for not being able to mind read that the example you have given is not what you really wanted the answer too!
[\sarcasm]

Comment: I didn't vote your down. Someone else did. And yours, for the record, wasn't a **right** answer.