# How to register a non-void function with atexit()?

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, atexit

I'm trying to register a function that returns an `int` to be called at the end of a program using the `atexit()` function. (Specifically, the [`endwin()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/endwin) function from ncurses.)

But since `atexit()` needs a pointer to a `void` function, I ran into a problem. I tried the following:

```
static_cast<void (*)()>(endwin)
```

but `static_cast`ing from an `int` function to a `void` function doesn't seem to be allowed.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible at all, and if yes, how?

**Note:** I'm willing to just ignore the return value of the function.

---

**Edit:** I also tried creating a lambda function, which seems to do what I want:

```
atexit([]{ endwin(); });
```

Is this a good solution compared to a wrapper/forwarding function? (Other than that it needs C++11 and avoids defining a new function whose sole purpose is just forwarding another function.)

Comment: Did you try a `reinterpret_cast` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: note that calling a function through a pointer of incorrect type results in undefined behavior according to 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] paragraph 6: "The effect of calling
a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined."

Comment: Yes, it is undefined, but I guess that on most Linux x86-64 implementations that won't matter. Of course, some ABI may specify different calling conventions (depending on the function signature), and in that case, chaos would happen

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That seems to work for me, but as Dietmar Kühl mentioned, it doesn't seem to be guaranteed to work.

Comment: If `endwin` is returning a complex data type, such as `std::string` or `struct X`, then it will return the data to a space given by some hidden argument. If the data type returned is "simple" (e.g. `int`, `char` or some pointer), the return value is passed in a register, and that's usually harmless. But Dietmar's solution is the "works all the time, every time" [and the compiler will probably optimis it so that it's very little overhead if anything in the case of "return value is in a register and therefore can be ignored]

Comment: The lambda is identical to a wrapper/forwarding function. it's just an anonymous wrapper/forwarding function.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Function pointers can't be converted. Just register a forwarding function:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void endwin_wrapper() { endwin(); }
...
atexit(endwin_wrapper);
```

Since you tagged your question C++: if you define the forwarding function in C++ you need to declare it to be `extern "C"` to have the proper language linkage.

Comment: Do you really need `extern "C"`? The name mangling doesn't matter a bit, the function pointer types of C and C++ are completely compatible, I thought. Unless there's some super-pedantic language-lawyer issue here...?

Comment: @NicholasWilson: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594178/why-do-you-need-extern-c-for-c-callbacks-to-c-functions

Comment: `atexit()` in C++ has two overloads, one of which is `extern "C++" int atexit(void (*f)(void)) noexcept;` which takes a C++ linkage function pointer. (The other is `extern "C" int atexit(void (*f)(void)) noexcept;`, taking a C linkage function pointer.)

Comment: What @T.C. said, but please note that if you inspect the standard library of any implementation that, contrary to the standard's requirements, does not distinguish between C and C++ linkage function types, you won't find the two overloads for `atexit` (and several other functions), since those implementations would fail to detect them as overloads.

Answer (score 12):

With the current C++ standard, a [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) is probably the best solution to this:

```
atexit([]{ endwin(); });
```

Now there's no need to define a whole new named function with the sole purpose of just forwarding another function.

---

And if you one day decide you need to have more functions called at program exit, you can either define them with a new call to `atexit()`:

```
atexit(anotherCleanupFunction);
```

or, you can just add them to the lambda body:

```
atexit([]{
  anotherCleanupFunction();
  endwin();
});
```

**However**, when you have multiple functions to be registered with `atexit()`, then a separate wrapper function to hold all those functions may be a better solution. There's no one right answer though, just write good and clear code. (A call to `atexit()` with by a lambda full of function calls can look rather messy.)

Comment: You may simply refer C++11 as _the current standard_. Otherwise,- as mentioned -, I like the solution.

Comment: True that would probably be better.

Comment: C++11 is not the current standard, C++14 is. In C++14, a lambda is still probably the best solution, so your answer still looks fine.

Comment: Best in what sense?  I think the wrapper solution is best, simply because it is perfectly clear what the author is doing, especially if a comment like "Needed to convert int return to void" is added.  There are people who write C & C++ code with the intention of getting a job done, not seeing how many obscure features they can include in the code.

Comment: @jamesqf Best in the sense that you don't need to define a whole new function just to be able to register that one non-void function with atexit(). But you do have a point, I would probably take the wrapper function route as well if I had multiple functions to register with atexit().

Comment: @zenith: Also from following the 'lambda' link above, and doing a quick bit of Googling, it seems that the lambda function only works in C++ (and perhaps as an extension in gcc?).  If so, it's not going to much use in C code, as the OP had the question tagged.  (Of course I could be wrong, as I'd never heard of lambda functions until I read this.)

Comment: @jamesqf Yeah you're right, lambdas were introduced in C++11. That's why I stated that this answer is specifically for C++ in case that C users come here looking for answers. Btw I'm the OP and I tagged this C because the question is also applicable to C. And from the `static_cast` in the question one can deduce that I'm doing C++ myself.

Answer (score 6):

> *"Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible at all, and if yes, how?"*

You just write your own wrapper function for `endwin()` and register that one

```
void myEndwin() {
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: Added an edit to my question about a lambda solution. (Just so you know, if you want to address that in your answer as well.)

Comment: @zenith You can also post your own answer mentioning it. That's a good solution.