# Can C++ code reliably interact with other C++ code?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, abi

In C, I'm used to being able to write a shared library that can be called from any client code that wishes to use it simply by linking the library and including the related header files. However, I've [read that C++'s ABI](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/181565/33920) is simply too volatile and nonstandard to reliably call functions from other sources.

This would lead me to believe that creating truly shared libraries that are as universal as C's is impossible in C++, but real-world implementations seem to indicate otherwise. For example, Node.js exposes a very simple module system that allows plain C++ functions (without `extern "C"`) to be [exported dynamically](http://lupomontero.com/writing-node-js-modules-in-cpp/) using the `NODE_SET_METHOD` function.

Which elements of a C++ API are safe to expose, if any, and what are the common methods of allowing C++ code to interact with other pieces of C++ code? Is it possible to create shared libraries that can expose C++ classes? Or must these classes be individually recompiled for each program due to the inconsistent ABI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, C++ interop is difficult and filled with traps.  Cold hard rules are that you *must* use the exact same compiler version with the exact same compiler settings to build the modules and ensure that they share the exact same CRT and standard C++ libraries.  Breaking those rules tend to get you C++ classes that don't have the same layout on either end of the divide and trouble with memory management when one module allocates an object using a different allocator from the module that deletes the object.  Problems that lead to very hard to diagnose runtime failure when code uses the wrong offset to access a class member and leaks memory or corrupts the heap.

Node.js avoids these problems by first of all **not** exporting anything.  NODE_SET_METHOD() doesn't do what you think it does, it simply adds a symbol to the Javascript engine's symbol table, along with a function pointer that's called when the function is called in script.  Furthermore, it is an open source project so building *everything* with the same compiler and runtime library isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This

> For example, Node.js exposes a very simple module system that allows
>   plain C++ functions (without extern "C") to be exported dynamically
>   using the NODE_SET_METHOD function.

Is wrong, you can see that they are using an an `extern "C"` there in the `init()` function, which is clearly what node.js is calling which is then forwarding the function on to which ever C++ function they want, which isn't exposed.

As explained in this question [How does an extern "C" declaration work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403391/how-does-an-extern-c-declaration-work) - When the compiler compiles the code, it mangles the function names, class names and namespace names. The reason it does this is because there can very easily be name clashes, for instance with overloaded functions.

Read about it more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

The only way to refer and lookup a function is if the `extern "C"` declaration is used, which forces the compiler to not mangle the name. I.e. in the example above, the function `init` will be called `init` where as the function `foo` will be called something like `_ugAGE` (I made this up, because it doesn't matter, it isn't for human consumption)

In summary, you can expose any C++ to any other language, but the entry point to the library must be one or more `extern "C"`'d global functions as they are the only way to refer to an unmangled name.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the C nor the C++ standards define an ABI. That is entirely left up to the implementation. The reason it's harder to get shared/dynamic libraries working for C++, is that C++ added things like classes, polymorphism, templates, exceptions, function overloading, STL, ...

So, the real source of information for you, is your compilers' documentation, as well as a corresponding set of guidelines for your library API to avoid any issues with any of the implementations your library will be built for. It's harder in C++ (the set of guidelines will likely be quite a bit bigger than for C, and you might have to work with a subset of C++), but not impossible.

Comment: The ABI for C is typically defined by *somebody* (the CPU manufacturer, or the OS vendor) and all compilers must follow it. This may also be true for C++, now, but traditionally has been much more implementation defined, and successive new features and bug-fixes have forced even those implementations to make changes. It isn't really anything to do with C++ being harder to define, although there is certainly more of it.

Comment: @ams : getting the same level of C++ ABI standardization as currently exists for C, is a matter of time. C++ is newer and more complex, which is why we're not there yet. It's a work in progress, yes, but the point I was trying to make is that the progress that has already been made can already be exploited to create C++ shared libraries. Probably not with the full C++ feature set, but still ...